React Component not rendering
So I'm currently following a course and at this point to a tee, even checked his GitHub which is the same. The thing is, none of my Header.jsx component is rendering. Here is my Header.jsx code:

and here is that page inspected, as you can see, it's empty:

and lastly, the App.jsx page, showing I've correctly imported Header.jsx. I've followed the tute to a tee.

Any views on this would be great, been messing with me for days.

replace [title] with {title} in NavLink props
